# Is read-write to an array of stack variables thread safe in GCD?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

Array of integers is allocated on stack and is being written to from two different threads.

Is the access to the holder[] is thread safe in the following code?

```
void some_function() {
    NSUInteger holder[256] = {0};
    NSUInteger *ptr_holder = holder;

    void (^countBlock)(<...>)= ^(<...>) {
        for (<...>) {
            ++ptr_holder[counter];
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    };

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        countBlock(<...>);
    });

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        countBlock(<...>);
    });

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    //Performing some work on holder[] from this point
}
```

If it's not thread safe design then why and how should it be improved?

Comment: How is it stack allocated if it's global? It seems to be statically allocated, and in that case, no, it's not safe. You need to synchronize access with a mutex or something similar.

Comment: Let's assume the code above is from the scope of a function. In that case as far as I can understand C `holder[]` will be allocated on that function's stack.

Comment: How can this be from "the view of a function"? They are defined at file-level, not even `static`, so with external linkage. Also, this is no C code. Please correct the tag. And provide a [mcve]. In C you cannot define a function in another function.

Comment: Removed C tag. Also edited the source to clarify the exact allocation of holder[]. In that particular case that's ObjC, though I thought the GCD library is applicable to C code.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where the memory for the array is allocated.  Reading raw memory is never thread-safe on its own, if there is at least one writer.  Obviously, if there are multiple writers, you have no thread-safety between them either. (Reading a single location may be atomic, but that's not the same as thread-safe.)

P.S. Your example code doesn't show any writing to `holder[]`.

Comment: `++ptr_holder[counter];` writes to to `ptr_holder` at index `counter`

Comment: Yeah, duh.  I've been in Objective-C land too long :)